# Javascript module pattern - page bindings

Tags: javascript, jquery, module-pattern

I am working out how to make my code more manageable and readable in a large application. I've read many posts and blogs about the module pattern and module revealing pattern but one thing which always seems to be missing is pages and bindings.

People show examples of modules, but I haven't found any good real work examples.

For example, lets say I have a page, which has a calculator on it.

All the examples I've seen show the calculator and how to create a module for that, but what I am looking for is how to get the page and the calculator to talk to each other.

Do people create a module for every page eg; CalculatorPage, do they have a binding or init method, and inside there they setup the calculator module? Here is some (invalid js) to sort of get the picture.

```
var Calculator
  settings: { resultElement },
  add (x, y) function to add and set resultElement to
  subtract (x,y) function to subtract and set resultElement to
```

then

```
var CalculatorPage
  ....
  bind (or init) = function() {
     this.calculator = new Calculator(.results);
     $('.add-button').on('click', this.calculator.add($('.x-field'.val(), $('.y-field').val());
     $('.subtract-button').on('click', this.calculator.subtract($('.x-field'.val(), $('.y-field').
```

- Should each page have a module?
- A nicer way to deal with bindings?

If someone had some better examples of modules in pages / real world applications I would really appreciate it..

Comment: This is really a "make it up as you go" thing, there's no right answer to this question. Do you need an object/module that covers the entire page somehow, if so make one, if not don't!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the question here is around the semantics of 'page'. If only a JS calculator is displayed then sure you could justifiably name the module 'calculatorPage'. For me though the word 'page' refers to the DOM. Personally I wouldn't couple the naming to the scenario that this must be the only thing on the page unless I felt sure that was the case and wanted to highlight it.

Setting up the bindings is a question of design. If you are using jQuery alone then you would want to set event handlers inside a DOM ready callback. If you want more of an MV* structure then you could use a framework like AngularJS or Backbone etc. which have their own abstractions. Basically though it comes down to the same thing, setting event listeners once the DOM is ready.